# Flex 4 new States format

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

Can someone explain how the new states work in flex 4 im migrating from flex 3 to flex 4 and i got an error in the states code:

```
<s:states>

        <s:State name="login"/>
        <mx:RemoveChild target="{viewStack}" />
        <mx:RemoveChild target="{header}" />
        <mx:RemoveChild target="{footer}" />
        <mx:SetStyle target="{login}" name="verticalAlign" value="middle" />

        <s:State name="menu"/>
        <mx:RemoveChild target="{login}" />
        <mx:AddChild relativeTo="{null}" >
            <search:Drawer title="{resourceManager.getString('locale','mySearch')}" 
                           dockSide="left" 
                           backgroundAlpha="0.9" 
                           backgroundColor="#ccccff">
                <search:SearchContent />
            </search:Drawer>
        </mx:AddChild>

    </s:states>
```

If u need the "target" code just tell here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show is a little too short to give you the exact code, but it should look something like this:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="login"/>
    <s:State name="menu"/>
</s:states>

<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" excludFrom="login" 
              paddingTop="15" width="100%" height="100%"/>

<s:HGroup id="header" excludeFrom="login" width="100%"/>
<s:HGroup id="footer" excludeFrom="login" width="100%" verticalAlign="bottom"/>

<mx:Box id="login" includeIn="login" width="100%" height="100%"
        horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"/>

<search:Drawer includeIn="menu" ... />
```

Basically, you use the `includeIn` and `excludeFrom` special attributes instead of the old `RemoveChild` and `AddChild` tags. Note that since there are only 2 states, `includeIn="menu"` and `excludeFrom="login"` have the exact same effect.
There's also the possibility of setting properties according to the current state, e.g.:

```
<v:MyComp left.login="0" left.menu="25"/>
```

Comment: i will put here the other code just to try to understand better.
**VIEWSTACK**<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" paddingTop="15" width="100%" height="100%" />
**HEADER**<s:HGroup width="100%" id="header" >
**FOOTER**<s:HGroup id="footer" width="100%" verticalAlign="bottom" >
**LOGIN**<mx:Box id="login" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" >

Comment: @TheJob I edited the answer according to the additional code you provided.

Comment: so in the header for exemple i use the <mx:RemoveChild target="{header}"/> in the flex 3, so now is not "...includein="menu"

Comment: @TheJob My apologies, I made a mistake: should have been `excludeFrom` for viewstack, header and footer. Edited again.

Comment: sry to pick up this again but now that i finally compiled the project i got an error in the search:drawer 

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: @TheJob Well obviously you have a nullpointer error. You'll have to be more specific than that.

Comment: im using the drawer from here http://kuwamoto.org/2006/04/10/new-flex-component-sliding-drawer-v-05/ i think is the implementation or something in flex 4

Comment: Is this Drawer where your error happens? It's clearly a Flex 3 implementation _and_ in perpetual beta.

Comment: yeah is a little bit old, yeah the error is in the drawer, im trying to search for something like that to implement in flex 4

Comment: Should be fairly easy to recreate using PopUpAnchor.

Answer (score 0):

The view states tag should only contain the states like so:

```
    <s:states> 
        <s:State name="State1"/> 
        <s:State name="State2"/> 
        <s:State name="State3"/> 
    </s:states>
```

Then, define state-specific property values for a component by using the dot (.) operator:

`propertyName.stateName`

For example:

```
<s:Button label="Play" label.State2="Stop" label.State3="Paused"/>
```

You can read more about states on Adobe Help pages for Flex 4.6 [Create and apply view states](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ffa.html)